# MySQL User Most Recent Record

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database that contains each API call that is made to my server. This table is used for various analytics. The table is structured as so:

```
---------------------------------------------
| user_id | api_call_time | app_version |
---------------------------------------------
1 | 2014-09-11 09:25:04 | v1

2 | 2014-09-11 09:26:06 | v1

1 | 2014-09-11 09:27:04 | v2
```

I am attempting to find out which users have switched to the new version (ie which ones have at least one record with `v2` in their `app_version` column. I have tried two methods, one doing a search `WHERE app_version = 'v2'`, and then another using `SELECT MAX(api_call_time),app_version FROM...` but in both cases it is not selecting the correct results.

What is the best way to go about finding which users have a record containing `app_version = v2`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you.
I think this query can help you:

**edit:**

```
select count(user_id) as count,user_id from you_table where app_version = 'v2' group by user_id
```

This query will return the one row with user_id and count of user_id which have app_version = v2

Comment: Ah I didnt make it clear, I would like it to be per `user_id`, rather than overall

Answer (score 0):

thins query will show you the users which called more than one time and at list one time with `'v2'`:

```
select user_id , count(app_version) 
from table_name 
where user_id in (select user_id from table_name where app_version='v2') 
group by user_id
having count(app_version) >1
```